# Solr - match exact number of multivalue fields

Tags: solr, solr4

I have the following in my docs:

```
<int name="groupCount">4</int>
<arr name="groupId">
    <str>1001</str>
    <str>1002</str>
    <str>1003</str>
    <str>1009</str>
</arr>
```

In my query I want to get all the documents where the user belongs to at least all of the groups the docs belong to.

So a user with groups:

```
1001
1002
1003
1009
1010
```

Will see the above doc as they are in all of the groups specified in the doc.

A user with groups:

```
1001    
1002
1003
1010
```

Will not as they are missing group 1009.

To do this I have added a groupCount field to the docs that tells me how many groups the doc is in. The plan being that I can check the number of matches of user groups to doc groups and compare that to the groupCount field. If they are the same then the user can see the doc.

To do this I was hoping to subtract the groupCount from the number of hits to get a zero - if the user is in all groups I get 0 - the user can see the doc.

I have the following query:

```
fq={!frange l= 0 u=0}sub(groupCount,sum(termfreq(groupId,1001),termfreq(groupId,1002),termfreq(groupId,1003),termfreq(groupId,1009)))
```

As you can see - for the above document I would expect the sum of all the termfreq queries to return 4 as there are 4 hits. sub(groupId, 4) should return 0

```
{frange l=0 u=0} 0
```

Should return that document.

But it's not working.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: iwayneo did u find the solution of this problem?

Comment: Are you getting any exception? What's happening when you execute the query?

Comment: I checked your query. It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, multivalued fields are processed in searches as 'at least one match' - Two approaches come to mind that may work for you:

Create a separate collection that has each user/group as it's own doc.  It sounds a little overkill, I understand, but if you only have a few fields, and they are indexed, but not stored, the impact will likely not be too bad.  You could manage the cross-collection queries manually, or try to leverage joins:
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join

Another option would be to structure the memberships as sub-documents and use block queries to try to filter out entries where the children meet your criteria.  see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers
for more info.